# Read jboss datasource password from web API

Tags: configuration, jboss, jboss7.x, cyber-ark, password-manager

My standalone.xml file in jboss server reads datasource passwords from a vault stored in the filesystem.

I am configuring a new password server, where password of the account can be retrieved via a secure web API.

How can I change my jboss setup to get data source passwords from the web API replacing the current vault?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to utilize the [Application Server Credentials Provider (ASCP)](https://docs.cyberark.com/Product-Doc/OnlineHelp/AAM-CP/Latest/en/Content/CP%20and%20ASCP/lp_ascp.htm?tocpath=Get%20Started%7COfferings%7C_____2) for JBoss that is provided by CyberArk. This will allow you to install the ASCP plugin in JBoss that will redirect your application's calls to the Vault in JBoss to the CyberArk Vault instead. This requires NO CODE CHANGES to your application, as CyberArk will just redirect where the secrets are fetched from in the middleware platform.